# Graph TranslateExchangeIds Unable to read beyond the end of the stream

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am using the Graph API from Outlook. I lately figured out, that it is using MessageIDs, that will change on every movement of a mail.
I found this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-immutable-id

Now I am trying to update my store accordingly to the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-translateexchangeids?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

```
var client = GraphServiceClientProvider.GetApplicationGraphServiceClient();
var reg = new Regex(@"=*$");
var idsToTranslate = worklist.GroupBy(i => i.MessageId)
  .Select(e => e.Key)
  .Distinct()
  .Select(e => reg.Replace(e.Replace("+", "-").Replace("/", "_"), m => 
    m.Value.Length.ToString()));

var translatedQueryResult = client.Users[fixupPostbox]
  .TranslateExchangeIds(idsToTranslate.ToArray(), ExchangeIdFormat.RestImmutableEntryId, 
     ExchangeIdFormat.RestId)
  .Request()
  .PostAsync()
  .Result;
var translatedResult = translatedQueryResult.ToDictionary(r => r.SourceId, r => r.TargetId);
```

I am wondering why it tells me it is 'Unable to read beyond the end of the stream.'

[image: Debugger Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The solution was minimize the page size, so instead of asking for 100 IDs per request, I changed the request to 25 IDs per request. It is working now.